# Why does the d'tor is called although it shouldn't?

Tags: c++, class

I tried to initiallize my own int array's class but somthing in the operator overloading isnt working, for somereason my object's d'tor is being called before I want it to and it makes my code crash:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Array.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Array arr(6);
    arr[3] = 6; //code crashes here
    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

and now the class:
header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <malloc.h>
class Array
{
public:
//ctor dtor and operator overloading
    Array(int);
    Array(int *, int);
    ~Array();
    Array operator[](int i);
//here memebers are defined
    int *arr;
    int size;
};
```

----cpp file---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Array.h"

//the function mallocs size for the array.

Array::Array(int g = 1) :size(g) //diplomatic value for size =1
{
    this->arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * this->size);

}
Array::Array(int *p, int m_size=1) :arr(p), size(m_size)
{} 

Array::~Array()
{
    delete arr;
}
```

after this function my object is being deleted by the d'tor

```
Array Array::operator[] (int i){
    for (int j=0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        ++(this->arr);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: None of this code makes any sense at all. But your big problem is that you fail to follow the Rule of Three correctly.

Comment: I cannot believe that code compile

Comment: Actually, this code is brilliant. Not for its assumedly intended purpose, but as an example. This code seems to be well-formed for miraculous reasons, but almost every part of it does something completely different from what common idioms and expectations would suggest.

Comment: It's not the problem, but please, never use a `malloc()` in C++ use `new` instead !

Comment: @ItayBraha What on earth is the `operator[]` supposed to do?! It increments `arr` a few times and then returns a copy of `*this`…?

Comment: the operator [] is supposed to recive an int and use it as an array's index, my array's pointer starts from the begging of the array and jump from one int to the next until it gets to the right one @Biffen

Comment: @ItayBraha A sensible implementation would return an `int&` and *not* make any changes to `arr`. I get the feeling you don't really know what your implementation does.

Comment: Seriously -- this code has so many mistakes that maybe you should just see how a properly implemented array class is supposed to look like and thus learn that way.  That would be much more worthwhile than trying to guess what it should look like and write adhoc code based on guesses and assumptions.

Comment: @ItayBraha -- You can [use this as an example](http://ideone.com/gXcHzF).  Yes, you may not understand everything, but that's the real point.  You didn't understand everything to write such a class, so instead of guessing, the code at the link at the very least gives you a starting point in terms of where to start proper research on writing such a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `operator[]` function returns an `Array` object by value. That means when you do your assignment `arr[3] = 6` the operator returns a copy of `this`, the compiler then implicitly creates an array object from the integer `6` (because it has a matching constructor) and suddenly your assignment looks like

```
arr[3] = Array(6);
```

Somewhere the temporary array objects (the one returned by the `operator[]` function, and the one the compiler creates on the right-hand side of the assignment) have to be destructed, but by then you have multiple object all using the same pointer `arr` inside themselves. The first temporary object is destructed and it deletes the pointer, leaving all other objects with an invalid pointer. Then the next temporary object is destructed and tries to delete the now invalid pointer. Boom, you have a crash.

There are two things you need to do to fix the problem. The first is to realize that the `operator[]` function returns the wrong type, it should return a reference to an element of the contained array instead:

```
int& Array::operator[](size_t const i)
{
    return arr[i];
}
```

The second thing you need to do is to read about [the rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Also, to prevent the compiler from mistakenly construct an object from an `int` value, you should mark the constructor as `explicit`:

```
explicit Array(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The main problem**

Regardless of other problems in your code, the signature of your `operator[]` is wrong:

```
Array Array::operator[] (int i){
     ...
}
```

You don't return an element of the array here ! You return a whole new array instead.  So in your faulty statement, a new temporary Array gets constructed and gets destructed at the end of the enclosing expression.

Try this instead. At least it will not crash immediately:

```
int& Array::operator[] (int i){
    return arr[i];
}
```

**The cause of the crash**

Unfortunately, you allocate arr using `malloc()`.  Never do this in C++ but use `new[]` instead. This would not lead to a crash by itself. But in addition in your destructor you use `delete`.

It's either `malloc()`/`free()` or `new`/`delete` or `new[]`/`delete[]`  Any other combination is undefined behavior (this causes the crash in your original code, when the temporary `Array` got destroyed).

Correct the problem as follows:

```
Array::Array(int g = 1) :size(g) //diplomatic value for size =1
{
    arr = new int[size];
}
Array::~Array()
{
    delete[] arr;
}
```

It will compile and work: [online demo](https://ideone.com/ifMklO)

**Other serious issue**

Finally to make the things even worse, your original indexing operator returns `*this`, making so a clone of your existing `Array`.  This is now solved.  But if you'd make any copy of your Array you'd have another problem:

This will cause the `arr` pointer to be used in two places. The first  `Array` that gests destructed will invalidate the `arr` pointer that is used in the  original `Array`.  Any subsequent dereferencing of its `arr` would be undefined behavior.

It's not solved in my online demo, so I I'd strongly suggest to read about the [**rule of 3**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))